# Is this RPI 3 B+ fixable, overvoltage on usb micro

Tags: pi-3b+, electronics

I cant identify the component that blew, any help idenitying it would be appreciated. Is it possible to replace it to save this rpi?

desoldered from the pads exposed on the right of the usb micro port

[image: rpi with blown component]

Comment: You can get a complete set of spare parts ready assembled for $35

Comment: The component is most likely a TVS diode. If you managed to blow this it is inconceivable that the Pi survived. If it doesn't work without, replacing it won't help, as it is not necessary.

Comment: If you take @Milliways option you'll gain with 2GB of RAM and a faster processor. The only extra cost will be a new power supply or a microUSB to USB-C adapter. Mostly there are no user replaceable parts on any Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to replace it to save this rpi?

Maybe... But it is literally impossible for anyone here (remote, no hands-on) to tell you if your board is repairable or not. I don't know if the odds improve significantly if we were "hands-on".

All you can do is try replacing the component that you blew off the board, and see what happens. The RPi Organization doesn't even publish complete schematics of the board, but [partial ones are available here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md).

And of course *economics* will enter into it at some point: how much time and effort would you be willing to spend to avoid a $35 outlay?